# Using Parse saveAllInBackground and beforeSave functions together

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform, cloud

I am working on an app which use cloud services provided by Parse.com.

In the app, we need to save multiple records at once and we use the following code to save our product array.

```
[PFObject saveAllInBackground:productArray block:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    if(succeeded){
        NSLog(@"Saved");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }
}];
```

We also need to avoid duplicating the same record and we use following cloud function in order to avoid it.

```
  var Product = Parse.Object.extend("Product");
  Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("Product", function(request, response) {
  if (!request.object.get("productId")) {
      response.error('Products should have a Product Id');
  } else {
    var query = new Parse.Query(Product);
    query.equalTo("productId", request.object.get("productId"));
    query.first({
    success: function(object) {
      if (object) {
        response.error("A Product with this productId already exists.");
      } else {
        response.success();
      }
    },
    error: function(error) {
      response.error("Could not validate uniqueness for this Product object.");
    }
  });
  }
  });
```

Our problem is when the saveAllInBackground method has worked with 1000 items and if there are couple of duplicated values, the all process is affected.

For example, we send 1000 items at once and there are 5 duplicated items in this 1000 and we expect the remaining 995 to be saved as new records. However, this is not the case at the moment. It seems that the all saving process is affected by the error message sent for a single record.

Any feedback will be appreciated.